# Cleaning carpet after candle hot liquid

Tags: repair, carpet

We got candle pot for scent which was dropped by a guest and the hot candle separated into the carpet. How can I take it off? It is like the candle it isfrozen onto carpet .

Comment: Two methods possible method:  buy a block of dry ice and put it on top until the wax is brittle and you can break it off.   Harder to find is old fashioned blotter paper, it’s still around but very hard to find, put it over the spot and apply heat with an iron (not on steam).  I’ve heard that some brands of very exorbitant paper towel will also work, instead of blotter paper, but I’ve never tried that.

Answer (score 2):

My wife and daughter love those scented wax things, we have had several spills on carpet, I found making a dam around the area and filling with hot water the wax melted and floated to the surface a few seconds later the water was cool enough the wax became solid again then we used a dry towel to soak up the excess moisture. The water was not boiling hot just above the melting point of the wax. I figured out the temp needed by floating the plastic container that the cubes came in a pan of water on the stove once the wax melted I pulled the holder out let the water get a little warmer then filled my little dam (a hand towel) so the water was above the fibers. In 1 room the carpet backing is plastic and I was worried the hot water might damage the backing but it was fine, the second room this has happened in is wool carpet and it worked even better on that.